# How to join splitted files from Linux on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, zip

So i splitted up a huge file from my Ubuntu Machine (via the **split** command) into 2GB Chunks so i can download them easier.

Now i have them laying on my Network Share and i can't seem to figure out, how to select all the chunks at once.

I have found this command but i have not given my Chunks a name, like he did with Zipchunks.
[Command i found](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-split-zip-files-and-join-them-in-windows/)

```
copy /b ZIPCHUNKS* > reassembled-zip.zip
```

I have 99 Chunks in total, where the first one being called **xaa** and the last one **xdu**.
I'm wondering how i can select all of them for my command to work.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the order in which the files need to be assembled? If not you likely own't be able to reassemble them. If you do you can just rename them and/or if they order naturally you'd just use `x*`. What parameters did you use for split?

Comment: The order naturally so i can use `copy /b x* > reassembled-zip.zip` - thank you i am going to try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok if i use that command i generate a 1kb rar file and in the terminal it's done right away, maybe there something running in the background

Comment: You could try to use `type * > ..\result.zip` but this might have issues with binary files. With Copy you'd need to use `copy file1+file2 result`. Total Commander features a `Combine Files` option that might be helpful.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick response, so i have tried the combine files in Total Commander, but that didn't work. With copy file1+file2 result you mean for example: `copy xaa+xbb > result.zip` than `copy result+xcc > result2` or how can i understand that?

Answer (score 1):

Your command:

`copy /b x* > reassembled-zip.zip`

is almost right but it should be:

`copy /b x* reassembled-zip.zip`

The first one is more Linux-like, where the command would just output data to stdout and that data would be redirected to the file, but the syntax is incorrect and anyway IIRC redirecting binary data does not work well on Windows. For the second one it's the `copy` command that creates the output file, without shell redirection at all.

The small file that you got with the first command is just the text output (messages, errors, etc) of the command, you can open it with a text editor.

Comment: Ohhhhh, thank you - didn't see that haha and know it makes more sense :)